# Visual Studio 2012 won't debug a library if it is also in the GAC

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, class-library

This is not related to the "just my code" debug setting, or marked Optimize Code, or not marked Debug code... all these situations had been ruled out.

I have a .net project that uses a library.
In order to debug I created a small project and then added the project for the library.
I added the reference for the library project in the test project.
I ran the solution starting the test project and I see my breakpoints change to hollow red dots. This same setup works perfectly in Visual Studio 2005.

But, I remembered I had the same library installed in the GAC and I removed, now, my breakpoints are hit correctly.

Does anybody know if this behavior is new in VS 2012? or anybody that has suffer it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will happen when the debugger cannot find symbol information for your assembly.  A somewhat likely scenario since the PDB file won't be present in the GAC.  Use Debug + Windows + Modules and locate the assembly in the list.  Right-click it and choose Symbol Load Information to see where the debugger looked for the PDB file.

Do avoid using the GAC on your dev machine, it is a pure deployment detail.  It causes nothing but accidents while you are programming.  Like having trouble with pdb files and  getting a stale copy of the assembly loaded.  Having to use the GAC while debugging should only happen in odd-ball interop scenarios.

Comment: ... or if you are building some infrastructure like compiler / build services a.s.o which expect things to be found in the GAC.